# How to declare a variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables

I should set VARIABLE in mysql query but not work: can you help me, where is the error?

```
SET @variabile = ( SELECT `submit_time` AS 'Submitted', 
                           max(if(`field_name`='N_PROGRESSIVO', `field_value`, null )) AS 'N_PROGRESSIVO', 
                           max(if(`field_name`='Submitted From', `field_value`, null )) AS 'Submitted From', 
                           GROUP_CONCAT(if(`file` is null or length(`file`) = 0, null, `field_name`)) AS 'fields_with_file' 
FROM `wpcust_cf7dbplugin_submits` 
WHERE `form_name` = 'Modulo SDO 2022 BS' 
GROUP BY `submit_time` 
ORDER BY `submit_time` DESC 
                ) as variabile);
```

Comment: please show the actual error message you got

Comment: Is there  a +1 parenthesis ? `)`

Comment: your select is returning multiple columns; what do you want to be stored in the variable?  it can't be all of them, unless you use multiple variables, which requires different syntax.  but it is also returning multiple rows; what do you expect to happen to their values?

Comment: it would help a lot to show what you want to do with the variable(s) once you have them set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT col1 INTO @variable1 FROM ... LIMIT 1
SELECT col1, col2 INTO @variable1, @variable2 FROM ... LIMIT 1
```

> The number of variables must be the same as the number of columns or
> expressions in the select list. In addition, the query must returns
> zero or one row.
>
> If the query return no rows, MySQL issues a warning of no data and the
> value of the variables remain unchanged.
>
> In case the query returns multiple rows, MySQL issues an error. To
> ensure that the query always returns maximum one row, you use the
> LIMIT 1 clause to limit the result set to a single row.

Source
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-select-into-variable/